# The pros and cons of different ways to serve and play wav audio files, from Node to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, http-live-streaming

As I see it we can use native [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) with `src`, serve a file or stream from Node.js and have a native player consuming that and producing sound.

We can also split it into chunks (HLS/RTMP) and consume them with a JavaScript player that can use it like [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) or [mediaelement](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement). This would help in cases of long audio files (and possibly heavy) so we can start to play before we have all the content. I saw also an interesting project [using websockets](https://github.com/scottstensland/websockets-streaming-audio).

What other ways are there? what are the pros and cons of each? does any of these as the "pro" of being able to encrypt the content being served?

Comment: Stream audio using 206 response has many pros (while the biggest con is mainly higher dev and maintenance effort) - low initial data = better site performance, users can start streaming from a later point, it makes possible to "record" (=download) parts of the audio, you can theoretically serve the chunks async, thus increase server performance. Maybe I find a more comprehensive summary and make an answer the next days

Comment: @Jankapunkt please do

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting audio/video can be done manually by your server. Ideally, using streams.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto")
const fs = require("fs")

const browser = getClientConnectionSomehow()

const encryptor = crypto.createCipheriv("aes256", "32 character long string", Buffer.alloc(16))

fs.createReadStream("path/to/video.mp4").pipe(encryptor).pipe(browser)
```

You can then send this to the client in a big stream.
Another, probably better way to do this, is have the client establish a WebSocket, with the client requesting chunks of video, and the server using `writeStreams` to pipe the selected portions down to the client.

I ran a quick test on my browser with a 1-minute video and localhost. It just pipes the video to the client, no throttling, and works very well. I didn't implement throttling, but in **pseudo-code** terms, the way I would do that is:

Client:

```html
<video src="/path/to/video">

</video>
```

```js
let video = document.getElement("video")
WebSocket.send((currentVideoBuffer - video.currentTime) >= 10)
// say, we wait until there are 10 seconds left in the video to load the next chunk.
```

Server:

```js
http.createServer((req,res) => {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream("path/to/video.mp4")
    WebSocket.on((shouldSend) => {
        if (shouldSend) {
            res.write(stream.read(500000)
            // just a dummy number of bytes. change as needed.
        }
    })
})
```

This is grossly oversimplifying how it really would work. You'd need to improve on the pseudo code a lot before it would actually be a viable option. But for livestreaming audio/video, this basically describes all the backend needs. I suggest using this option if you need encryption, too, but I have **no** idea how the browser would decrypt it and then shove it in an audio element.

Streaming from nodejs to the client is fairly simple (with express, just hook up `res.write` to the read function of a `readStream` from FS.)

Node is built for streaming content, and I suggest looking into their native tools. I have not looked into the libraries you've linked, but they seem like viable options.

I think it all comes down to how much tooling you'd want. With your own custom implementation, you'd get to add and remove features to make your dream video/audio player. (I'm sure there is a way, like with Opus streams, to downgrade quality of some streams, making some take less kb/s).

I suppose using a pre-made library is best for getting off the ground, but if your project revolves around this streaming, or you require something like AES-256 or anything unorthodox, I suggest making your own implementation. As I've demonstrated above, it's complex, but not too hard, thanks to nodejs.

---

**Edit**

I've found this NodeJS project. It's a video parser, which lets you split a video into chunks of buffers (and get the buffer's length!). This should help you split and stream the buffers.

https://github.com/gkozlenko/node-video-lib

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is the type of the data sent in a stream? What will the encrypt tool receive in `.pipe(encryptor)`? If I wanted to change the compression rate because the users network degraded what would be a good option in that case? (start a new stream with compression or switch the compression inside the open stream?)

Comment: The way streams work is you "read" a piece of data, and process it. A stream is split up into multiple chunks of Buffers, which can be "read". ( the same is true for write streams, like the "response" http object ). The encrypt tool supports this built-in, so all you will have to do is pipe it through, and pipe the output into a writestream (send it to the client or something). If you want to compress it, there is a built-in library that has the exact same functionality. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_options (you can even change compression level!) (1/2)

Comment: Performance-wise, it would probably be best to run a few compression streams (low, medium, high) and then split the output to different clients. If you're compressing a stream for every client where the results are identical, then you're wasting computer power. iirc, you can pipe a stream to multiple outputs (so, you can send the same file's readStream to multiple http responses). It's probably best to look into the nodeJs "stream" module for more information :) (2/2)

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a music streaming platform. We had to serve upto 1-2 GB audio files as stream. So I did this. Used [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) library for formatting the uploaded audio. ffmpeg should be installed on your machine.

```
require('child_process').exec(`ffmpeg -y -i ${dir_str} -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_format mpegts -segment_list "${m3u8_path}/${soundId}.m3u8" -segment_list_type m3u8 "${m3u8_path}/ts%d.ts"`)
```

I think this has the pro of encyrption.